# ListItem's value gets replaced by the text on DataBind

Tags: c#, .net, radiobuttonlist, listitem, data-binding

I'm at a bit of a loss on this one and haven't been able to find anything helpful in my searches so I'm hopeful someone can help me out here.

I've got a RadioButtonList that I'm adding a List of dynamically created ListItems, where I set both the text and the value for each item.  On DataBind for the RadioButtonList the Value for the ListItem gets replaced by the Text, which just doesn't seem to make sense to me.

I can see on the client side when I look in Firebug that the label and the value on the input are the same, and the value is nowhere to be seen.

Has anyone else had any experiences like this, or does anyone know where I might be going wrong?

```
var rbList = new List<ListItem>();
var radioButtonList = new RadioButtonList();
foreach(var object in objects) {
  var li = new ListItem {Text = object.Name, Value = object.Guid};
  rbList.Add(li);
}
radioButtonList.DataSource = rbList;
radioButtonList.DataBind();
```

Comment: Where's the definition of 'objects'?

Comment: You are mixing two different approaches how to fill RadioButtonList with data! This is not correct. Either you add ListItem-s to radioButtonList.Items (as below) or you use radioButtonList.DataSource and supply some set of non-ListItem objects (typically Entitites) - therefore the behavior you encountered is correct

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Should you be using Databinding here? Can you not just add your ListItems to the radio button list directly?

I would imagine that the Databinding is getting confused about how to bind your list so is just using ToString on each of your elements which seems to just return the `Text` Property. This is then being used as both the Text and the Value.

You probably just want to create your items and add them straight to your Radio button control as follows:

```
var radioButtonList = new RadioButtonList();
foreach(var object in objects) {
  var li = new ListItem {Text = object.Name, Value = object.Guid};
  radioButtonList.Items.Add(li);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed my problem.  Your explanation about the why seems to make sense as well.  You are a life and sleep saver!

Comment: Glad to have helped. You can +1 me as well if you are that enamoured by the solution (it hit the up arrow above the number). ;-) Glad to have helped though. Its what we're here for. :)

Comment: Not enough reputation yet.  I have been a lurker for years, but this is my first case of any sort of active involvement.  I will make sure to come back when I'm allowed to.

Comment: Ah. I assumed you could vote up on your own question answers, even if not others (in the same way you can comment on your own).

Comment: Went out and grabbed some more reputation this week.  Came back in to give you another upvote.

Answer (score 0):

For those, whose are still struggling - do not forget to fill DataValueField, if control has it. Simply provide string name of your value property and you will be fine.

As Chris mentioned - Databinding was in fact confused and therefore DataValueField exists. My problem was with basic asp:DropDownList.